# Single image different background

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, image

I don't really know what im searching for even after googling all sorts and wondered if someone could put me in the right direction.

Lets base this example on a car frame.

I would like to have one image of a car frame which allows to have multiple colours (Hex), so when a user selects black, the main car colour is black but the shape/frame of the car remains with the same image, selecting red would change the colour but would keep the same frame image.

The reason why i would like to have one image is, because there could be 50-60 cars all with around 20-30 different colours. So uploading that many images would consume a lot of disk space over time.

Any components/frameworks i could use with an ASP net project?

Comment: Your image is standard jpeg or something like this?

Comment: So far yes but i can change the image to whatever is required - I dont know why ive been down voted since ive clearly explained!! perhaps the clever person that down voted could explain!!

Comment: Most likely because you haven't thoroughly explained any research attempts, save from the brief mention of Googling, and haven't provided any examples of what you've tried so far to make this work.

Comment: @Computer All that **I** know - is the long way with different images. I didn't hear about such frameworks as you mentioned and highly doubt that they exists. If they are - i'm interested to know

Comment: @JacobBarnes - even if i did explain in through, i dont think anyone would up vote my post - see my past questions where ive explained in detail and never get an up vote.

Comment: This suggestion is probably simplistic... Could you make your image such that the part with variable color is transparent (or translucide where gray shading is needed), and then show that image inside of a div container (or a span, as long as the container is completely filled by the image). By changing the background color of the container, that color would show through the transparent part of the image, as if the object on the image itself had that color.

Comment: @Computer, completely understandable. I personally wouldn't have down voted this, but I'm sure my comment reflects the down voter's thinking.

Comment: maybe overlaying svg on top of the image? I've never tried it, but if you got the co-ordinates right you might then be able to fill an area. Or try the HTML5 canvas element. They're not asp-specific components, just functionality available in modern browsers.

Comment: http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer/#demo

Comment: Wouldn't it be complicated if you want the color change to look realistic with glare on the car and whatnot?

Comment: There is a technique you can use where you overlay "skins" onto the car using an SVG image file since SVG images are capable of changing colors.  So 1 image would be the car and the other would be an svg blank skin that has its color manipulated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either client side Html and Javascript:

1. You could do this efficiently by creating a partially transparent image I guess. Then change the background color of the element below the image using script. It depends on the type of picture and quality of the output if this is an option for you.
2. A better approach would be to change the color of pixels directly. Look for Html5 canvas pixel manipulation or use this link: [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas). Scroll down to the Grayscale sample to start with.

Or server side C#:

3. Use image filters/direct pixel manipulation. Look for "Pixel Manipulation in C#" to find the right libs and API for your project and framework e.g. [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). More choices here: [.NET Core Image Processing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/).